# How to listen to any keyboard on the whole application?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

We are trying to build android activity that listen to any key press (either character or command) something like custom `EditText`.

1. Is there something like keyboard hook in `Windows OS` available on Android?
2. Is it possible to listen for all key pressed for all controls (`EditText` and other controls)?
3. Could this be achieved by an activity that runs in the background?

**EDIT**

As for security, we want to get keyboard events only for our app activity, ex: when our activity is shown and focused.

Comment: We have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

The Activity's [onKeyDown / up / etc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) method will get called if no View consumes the event.

When Views do consume the events, you will need either:

1. a custom version of each relevant class that forwards the key presses up to the activity.
2. add a [text change listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) or [key listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setKeyListener%28android.text.method.KeyListener%29) to all TextViews in the view hierarchy (could use a recursive method to step through the entire hierarchy)

Comment: What about creating a service that will listen to key events directly when our activity is focuses? would this break security rules?

Comment: Yes, if your service is your keyboard (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#). Otherwise the only thing a normal service would help is to persist the state of the history of key presses.. the activities would still have to report to the service their key presses.

Answer (score 1):

You can't listen for `EditText` keys from background process, as it is bounded to Keyboard activity that manipulate that text. It will be security valuation as it will not only allow you to listen to keys in your own application but for all others, including sensitive data like user passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Handling Keyboard Actions
 
http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html

An event listener is an interface in the View class that contains a single callback method. These methods will be called by the Android framework when the View to which the listener has been registered is triggered by user interaction with the item in the UI.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventListeners

Answer (score 0):

Android soft keyboard does not create any events so there is no good way of listening for keyevents ... you can use add a TextWatcher ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html ) to a hidden edittext.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/input/InputManager.html

As per documentation this has a nested class

Nested Classes
interface --    InputManager.InputDeviceListener -- Listens for changes in input devices.

Just a lead, not sure about the usage though